# Smooth animation on outerglow with WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, animation

I have `ToggleButton` with an `OuterGlowBitmapEffect` applied to it. I animate this glow to give it a pulsating effect, drawing peoples attention to it. My problem is, if I slow the animation down for the duration of a second, it stutters a lot. How can I prevent the stutter from occurring and what is it that's causing it to not be smooth?

Here is the button:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnMap1" Click="btnMap1_Click" Style="{DynamicResource GenericButton}" Width="152" Height="127" IsChecked="True">
    <ToggleButton.BitmapEffect>
        <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="White" GlowSize="0" Noise="0" Opacity="1" />
    </ToggleButton.BitmapEffect>
</ToggleButton>
```

And here is the animation:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ButtonGlow" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="30">
    <DoubleAnimation 
            BeginTime="00:00:00"
            Storyboard.TargetName="btnMap1"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.BitmapEffect).(OuterGlowBitmapEffect.GlowSize)"
            From="0.0"
            To="10.0"
            Duration="0:0:1"
            AutoReverse="True"
            />
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This effect is very CPU intensive, as it is software-rendered rather than GPU-generated.

[Microsoft has deprecated this and similar effects and discourages their use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.outerglowbitmapeffect.aspx).

> Bitmap effects should not be applied
>   to large visuals or animations because
>   this can degrade performance.

They suggest using [`BlurEffect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.blureffect.aspx) instead.